# Finding a Noether Normalization for

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have difficulty on how to find Noether normalization of the following

Comment: You need to find a maximal algebraically independent set. Do you really have no idea how to do this? You can't find even 1 transcendental element?

Comment: For the first one, $x^2 - yz$ is a monic polynomial in which variable? For the second, both $x$ and $y$ are transcendental but if you choose either of them are you left with an integral extension? So what might you need to do?

Comment: To help "exercise it on other problems,", here is another [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2540092/29335), and [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1819631/29335)

Comment: Why di you deface your own post?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the first one is a surface in 3-space, and you can pick a projection on one of the coordinate planes. The other example is similar.